# Image Upload from React to Express server with Multer

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, file-upload, multer

I get `undefined` when I try to read the `req.files` and if I read `req.body` I get `file: [object Object]` which, when read on the front end before being sent is

`Icon: File(4076381)
lastModified: 1513292207750
lastModifiedDate: Thu Dec 14 2017 17:56:47 GMT-0500 (EST) {}
name: "image.jpeg"
size: 4076381
type: "image/jpeg"
webkitRelativePath: ""`

but after

```
let upload =  new FormData();
upload.append('file', user);
console.log(upload);
```

upload logs `FormData = {}` so I have no idea why `.append()` did not work. `user` is the Icon object shown above.

but when sent back it is the same `[object Object]` as on the server of course.

I am trying to understand why req.file is not readable or any other alternative for how to read the uploaded file so that I can then do whatever I want with it (end game, store in a db as a field in mongodb, then pull out and render on the client side after logging in).

Relevant code

Register.js

```
  // standard React stuff

  handleUpload = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.files[0]);
    this.setState({ Icon: e.target.files[0] });
  };


  handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const dispatchObject = {
      Icon: this.state.Icon
    }
    await this.dispatchSubmit(dispatchObject);
  }

render(){
  return (
    <form noValidate autoComplete="off" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      />
      <Input
        id='Icon'
        type='file'
        name='Icon'
        accept='image/png, image/jpeg'
        onChange={this.handleUpload}
      />  
          <input type='submit' value='Submit'/>
    </form>
  )
}
```

action/index.js

```
export const register = (user, history) => {
  console.log(user);
  let upload =  new FormData();
  upload.append('file', user);
  return dispatch => {
    axios.post('http://localhost:9000/register', upload)
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data);
      console.log('User successfully created');
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err) );
  }
}
```

server.js

```
import multer from 'multer';

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: './files',
  filename(req, file, cb) {
    console.log(file);
    cb(null, `${new Date()}-${file.originalname}`);
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage });

app.post('/register', upload.single('file'), async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body.file);
  res.json(req.body.file);
});
```

Multer will create the relevant folder called ./file but there is never anything in it and req.file is not accessible. I cannnot send it through the body in a standard manner because it comes out in the `[object Object]` format.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was too change the below to `user.Icon`.

```
export const register = (user, history) => {
  console.log(user);
  let upload =  new FormData();
  upload.append('file', user);
```

I also separated any other files that I wanted to send in another api call.

Answer (score 0):

you are logging req.body.file but it is req.file.